# Logic behaves as if variable is NULL when it is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, bind

I have a encountered a very strange error. I have:

```
externalContactsGrid.bind('dataBound', function(e) {
    contactId = null;
    if (typeof e.sender._data[0] === 'undefined') {
        contactId = null;
    } else {
        contactId = e.sender._data[0].contactId
    }
    console.log(contactId)
    if (contactId === false) {
        alert(contactId)
        $('#externalContactsGrid .k-grid-content table').html('<tr role="row" class="no-results"><td role="gridcell">No results found</td></tr>');
    }
})
```

At the point of `console.log(contactId)` contactId is for example 2495, but when it hits the if it does not execute because apperently contactId is false (!). What could be causing this?

---

The weird thing is. is that the alert doesn't happen but the line after ($('#externalCon....) does.

The function is only executing once as I would see console log twice (i.e. 2495, and then null after it).

Comment: Actually, no, the block will execute only if `contactId` has a falsy value: `if (not false)` => `if (true)`. `2495` isn't falsy.

Comment: `!2495` is falsy because `2495` is truly, so...

Comment: `The weird thing is. is that the alert doesn't happen but the line after ($('#externalCon....) does` Now replicate your issue somewhere online, sounds like your are debugging/checking it wrongly

Comment: But how can only parts of an if statement run and not the others??

Comment: @imperium2335 That's not possible unless there is some script error which we cannot be aware of with your posted code... Like said, replicate your issue on jsFiddle if you can. And don't forget to clear cache if needed

Comment: It's basically thinking that 2945 === false, which is not true. :(

Comment: @imperium2335 every numbers are {true} except 0. Now regarding `contactId === false` is still wrong, you are btw checking for same type, meaning `contactId` needs to be boolean false

Comment: With `=== false`, `if` branch should be executed only if `e.sender._data[0].contactId` is `false`. Hint: `null === false` is `false`.

Comment: The fact that the second statement is executing would suggest that the `alert` line should also execute. Did you mean `window.alert`? What happens if you replace that line with `console.log(contactId)`?

Comment: Don't think this will change the outcome, but you have some missing semi-colons, which could potentially make your code behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon (a few, actually). Also, I think you're using the identity operator when you should be using the equality operator. If you want to compare values, use the equality operator.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 0):

This seems to only happen when I use Jquery's `.html()` method. I have instead used `.append()` and the problem no longer occurs.